# Developers Console showing stale memcache results?

Tags: google-app-engine, caching

[I believe this is an issue with Developers Console and not a programming question, but Google referred me to stackoverflow.]

Memcache results seem to be out of date on the Compute/App Engine/Memcache tab. Look at "ITEMS IN CACHE" (3 count) and the items in the list (14 count). After I "Flush cache", there are still items in the list, but when I "Find a key" in the list after "Flush cache" nothing is returned. That would mean, memcache seems to function as supposed but the website seems to show stale results.

[image: Memcache Tab from the Google Deverlopers Console]

The same problem occurs in Chrome and IE. Even when I reload the page and/or flush the browser cache, the site would still show stale results. Any workaround? Or do I overlook anything?

--

Now it becomes funny! I flushed memcache and added one item, but according to the console I have 3 items in cache with the single item displayed in the list being responsible for 250% of all traffic, lol. @Google, is this production or beta?

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the report; we're looking into this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR The list of keys is an approximation of the key activity over the last hour or so. It is not a representation of the current state of the cache – so it is expected that it might not match the “Items in Cache” count.

More details ...

App Engine dev here.  Thanks Oliver for pointing out this problem, you are right that output is confusing, and we need to fix either output or the explanation of what it represents.

Here's the problem.  The list of keys displayed was never meant to be an accurate reflection of the current state of the cache, especially for small caches.  It is meant to give you some idea of what are your “hottest” keys, and it is really intended only for apps with millions or billions of keys that might have a few hot keys that would prevent memcache scaling effectively.

When you buy more dedicated memcache from App Engine you don't just buy more gigabytes of memory, you also buy more  throughput (you get about another 10k key-operations-per-second for every 1 GB you buy).  However you will only be able to take advantage of all your purchased throughput if your keys are well distributed in their activity.  If you have a few hot keys then they could overload part of your memcache causing excessive latency or errors rates.

So to help make sure a large app can scale memcache effectively we show this list of your hottest keys. Calculating an exact “top K” list of keys for the massively distributed scale of our operations is prohibitively expensive so we make some approximations, one of which is to do the calculations in one-hour time buckets.

These approximations work well for large apps in steady state (which was our goal), but as you have discovered, they can produce anomalous results for small apps when the activity and contents of the app is changing.

These anomalous results for small apps were an oversight on our part, and I am going to file an internal bug to address it.  It may be that we just add some text to the user interface to make it clear that the list is an approximation of the key activity in the last hour or so, and not a representation of the current state of the cache.

Comment: May I make a suggestion? I do understand the ramifications and I was wondering how Google can query such huge amounts of keys. I believe the list should serve both purposes: While writing a new app with only a handful of keys, it would make debugging much easier if it would be possible to look up the exact keys. Once an app is in production, what you describe makes sense. Can't we have both? Either switch modes at a certain amount of keys/volume, or let the admin switch for debugging.

Comment: Yes, it would indeed be very useful when debugging with small amounts of data to see an exact representation of the cache.  I've added your suggestion for a "small-cache mode" to our internal bug.